# My swift app fail to convert NSData to Json

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsdata, nsjsonserialization

I was trying to convert NSData to Json by doing this:

```
    let jdata = getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/16j2i")

    do {
        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jdata, options: []) as! [String: AnyObject]
        print(json)
    } catch {
        print("\(error)")
    }
```

This is the getJSON method

```
func getJSON(url:String) -> NSData {
    return NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: url)!)!
}
```

A error says that could not cast value of type '_NSCFArray' to 'NSDictionary'. Any ideas? Please

Comment: array of dictionaries:  `[[String: AnyObject]]`

Answer (score 1):

The root element of your JSON is array not dictionary (Your format looks something like `[{...},{...}]` ). For fixing this error you need to change the parsing code to:

```
let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jdata, options: []) as! [[String: AnyObject]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
let convert_array = responseString?.description
// Convert server json response to NSDictionary
do {
    if let convertedJsonIntoDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSArray {
       print(convertedJsonIntoDict)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let data = text.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

> let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String:Any]
>
> Working Fine for Swift 3.1 & Swift 4

Comment: Please don't suggest `.mutableContainers`. The option is pointless in Swift.